aws s3 exporter error during otel configuration
can someone guide me what is wrong here
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "awss3": 2 error(s) decoding:
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * '' has invalid keys: tls
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * 's3uploader' has invalid keys: marshaler
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z 2024/06/03 18:31:50 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "awss3": 2 error(s) decoding:
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * '' has invalid keys: tls
2024-06-03 18:31:50.969Z * 's3uploader' has invalid keys: marshaler
I followed all the instructions but still end up with below error
